# Cannot move out of value which is behind a shared reference when unwrapping

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

This is the code I am trying to execute:

```rust
fn my_fn(arg1: &Option<Box<i32>>) -> i32 {
    if arg1.is_none() {
        return 0;
    }
    let integer = arg1.unwrap();
    *integer
}

fn main() {
    let integer = 42;
    my_fn(&Some(Box::new(integer)));
}
```

([on the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=851676c975e45fb28359f5f5a863f80e))

I get the following error in previous versions of Rust:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:5:19
  |
5 |     let integer = arg1.unwrap();
  |                   ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

And in more modern versions:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*arg1` which is behind a shared reference
 --> src/main.rs:5:19
  |
5 |     let integer = arg1.unwrap();
  |                   ^^^^
  |                   |
  |                   move occurs because `*arg1` has type `std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<i32>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
  |                   help: consider borrowing the `Option`'s content: `arg1.as_ref()`
```

I see there is already a lot of documentation about borrow checker issues, but after reading it, I still can't figure out the problem.

Why is this an error and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`Option::unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) consumes the option, that is, it accepts the option by value. However, you don't have a value, you only have a reference to it. That's what the error is about.

Your code should idiomatically be written like this:

```
fn my_fn(arg1: &Option<Box<i32>>) -> i32 {
    match arg1 {
        Some(b) => **b,
        None => 0,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let integer = 42;
    my_fn(&Some(Box::new(integer)));
}
```

([on the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e1e7c3e7bc6b3ba0f483033b01c3eaa9&version=stable&mode=debug))

Or you can use `Option` combinators like [`Option::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) or [`Option::as_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_mut) paired with [`Option::map_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or), as Shepmaster has suggested:

```
fn my_fn(arg1: &Option<Box<i32>>) -> i32 {
    arg1.as_ref().map_or(0, |n| **n)
}
```

This code uses the fact that `i32` is automatically copyable. If the type inside the `Box` weren't `Copy`, then you wouldn't be able to obtain the inner value by value at all - you would only be able to clone it or to return a reference, for example, like here:

```
fn my_fn2(arg1: &Option<Box<i32>>) -> &i32 {
    arg1.as_ref().map_or(&0, |n| n)
}
```

Since you only have an immutable reference to the option, you can only return an immutable reference to its contents. Rust is smart enough to promote the literal `0` into a static value to keep in order to be able to  return it in case of absence of the input value.

Comment: And what if I want to get a reference to the i32 inside the box (let's say I want to modify it and have another part of the program to see the changed value) ?

Comment: FWIW, I'd write it as `arg1.as_ref().map(|x| **x).unwrap_or(0)`

Comment: @Moebius, I've updated my answer with an example with references, however, I didn't exactly understand what do you mean about modifying values. An example would be helpful, but it probably deserves another question anyway.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev no special use case, I was just asking out of curiosity. Thanks for the solution !

Answer (score 1):

Since Rust 1.40 there is [`Option::as_deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref), so now you can do:

```
fn my_fn(arg1: &Option<Box<i32>>) -> i32 {
    *arg1.as_deref().unwrap_or(&0)
}
```