# Is there an alternative to `get_or_insert()` to pull out a reference of Option<T> without consuming it?

Tags: rust

I'd like to edit the content inside an `Option<T>` without consuming it. The code below seems one way, but I think the use of `get_or_insert()` is somewhat unnecessary and redundant.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct S {
    state: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = Some(S {
        state: String::from("Some is definitely set"),
    });
    let y: &mut S = x.get_or_insert(S {
        state: String::from("Just hack. This is definitely not going to be inserted"),
    });
    y.state = String::from("Check out x");
    println!("{:#?}", x);
}
```

Is there an alternative to `get_or_insert()` to pull out reference of `Option<T>` without consuming it?

Comment: I don't follow your logic. You have an `Option`, which means you don't know if the data is present or not. There's no way to get a reference to the data to mutate it if the `Option` is `None`. How would you want it to be more efficient? What should happen when it's `None`?

Comment: I guess `x.get_or_insert_with(|| None)` might be a little nicer (since it ensures that if the option is `None`, it stays `None`) but still -- it's an awkward construct.

Comment: @Shepmaster Well, to simplify, what I want is another version of `unwrap()` which panics or returns a reference.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Cannot cannot move out of value which is behind a shared reference when unwrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32338976/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your case](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2e11caad317657ab8b02cac8468b8c10)

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment, I guess you're after `x.as_mut().unwrap()`:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct S {
    state: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = Some(S {
        state: String::from("Some is definitely set"),
    });
    x.as_mut().unwrap().state = String::from("Check out x");
    println!("{:#?}", x);
}
```

Comment: Please search for duplicate questions before answering.