# Rust "if let" vs "unwrap" behavior

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, unwrap

I'm about a week into learning Rust, and I'm struggling to understand some of the nuances of ownership.  I have this code that works:

```
if let Some(node) = current {
    node.next = Some(Box::new(ListNode::new(sum_digit)));
    current = node.next.as_mut();
}
```

I thought that `if let Some(node) = current` was equivalent to assigning `node` the value of `current.unwrap()`.  However, the code below doesn't work:

```
current.unwrap().next = Some(Box::new(ListNode::new(sum_digit)));
current = current.unwrap().next.as_mut();
```

I receive the following error message:

```
46  |         let mut current = head.as_mut();
    |             ----------- move occurs because `current` has type `Option<&mut Box<ListNode>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
73  |                 current.unwrap().next = Some(Box::new(ListNode::new(sum_digit)));
    |                         -------- `current` moved due to this method call
74  |                 current = current.unwrap().next.as_mut();
    |                           ^^^^^^^ value used here after move
```

Is there a way to accomplish the same thing without using `if let`?  I know that `current` is not `None`, so that is safe.

Comment: Well what happens if you do assign `node` the value of `current.unwrap()`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I can use `let node = current.unwrap();`, then `node.next = Some(Box::new(ListNode::new(sum_digit)));`, then `current = node.next.as_mut();`, and that works.  I guess the question then is how can I modify `next` element within `current` directly without creating this new variable `node`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 This still doesn't make any sense to me, since `current.unwrap().next = Some(Box::new(ListNode::new(sum_digit)));` works, but following that with `current = current.unwrap().next.as_mut();' causes the error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot move out of value which is behind a shared reference when unwrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338659/cannot-move-out-of-value-which-is-behind-a-shared-reference-when-unwrapping)

Answer (score 4):

> I thought that `if let Some(node) = current` was equivalent to assigning `node` the value of `current.unwrap()`.

`current.unwrap()` will unconditionally consume `current`. Thanks to match ergonomics `if let` doesn't have to do that.

> Is there a way to accomplish the same thing without using `if let`? I know that current is not `None`, so that is safe.

`current.as_mut().unwrap()`? You're already using `as_mut`.

`Option::as_mut` will borrow the option, and create a new option with a reference to the contents of the existing one. You can consume *that* (by unwrapping) without affecting the original option.