# Unwrapping Option fields using &self in methods

Tags: rust

My type has one field which is an `Option`. I am writing a method that accesses the field via the object reference. However, I cannot unwrap the `Option` field because that would be moving stuff that is behind a shared reference (`&self`).

How do I then unwrap?

```
enum BOrC {
    B(String),
    C(u32)
}

struct A {
    x: Option<BOrC>
}

fn print_enum(v: BOrC) {
    match v { 
        BOrC::B(string) => println!("{}", string.as_str()),
        BOrC::C(number) => println!("{}", number),
    }
}

impl A {
    fn foo(&self) {
        let xx: BOrC = self.x.unwrap();   <--- The issue!
        print_enum(xx)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let one = A{x : Some(BOrC::C(12))};
    let two = A{x : Some(BOrC::B("today".to_string()))};
    one.foo();
    two.foo()
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.x` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:19:24
   |
19 |         let xx: BOrC = self.x.unwrap();
   |                        ^^^^^^ -------- `self.x` moved due to this method call
   |                        |
   |                        help: consider calling `.as_ref()` or `.as_mut()` to borrow the type's contents
   |                        move occurs because `self.x` has type `Option<BOrC>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |
note: `Option::<T>::unwrap` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `self.x`
  --> /rustc/79e9716c980570bfd1f666e3b16ac583f0168962/library/core/src/option.rs:932:25
```

The playground link is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=254ee66bb97656c59582e963a8b1c39d).

---

Note that this question has nothing to do with [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338659/cannot-move-out-of-value-which-is-behind-a-shared-reference-when-unwrapping): here we have `Option` and not `&Option`. One cannot pattern match on `&Option` as suggested by the answer simply because the reference is on `&self` and not on `Option`.

Comment: What happens when you try the compilers suggestions? (after `help:`)

Comment: @cafce25 Nothing useful. `self.x.as_ref()` will give you `&BOrC`, which you will need to dereference in the very next line. And `BOrC` does not implement `Copy`.

Comment: Well what do you expect, you only have a reference to begin with, that's not magically going to give you something owned.

Comment: I expect to access the field of an object. If `&self` is a reference to the object (just like in Java, for instance), then there should be a seamless way to access the fields of that object.

Comment: *"One cannot pattern match on `&Option` as suggested by the answer simply because the reference is on `&self` and not on `Option`."* - you can trivially get an `&Option` from `&self` like this: `&self.x`.

Comment: @kmdreko What is that supposed to achieve? As far as I can tell, doing that is not the same as having `&Option` as the function parameter (as in the supposed duplicate question). Try it in the playground.

Comment: @cafce25, do you still believe this is a duplicate question?

Comment: Yes, you simply can't get something owned from a reference so you *don't* have a `Option` but only ways to get a `&Option` (see also kmdrekos comment) to which the dupe trivially applies.

Comment: Your underlying problem here is print_enum, and the assumptions that come from it. You can't directly manipulate the fields of an object behind a &self. You can take references to them, and read copy fields, but thats it. Print_enum, as its not modifying the enum should take a reference, then you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Alternatively, if foo needs to take ownership, it can't take a reference, it needs to take a value.

Comment: @user1937198 if that is the explanation, then it cannot possibly be a duplicate of the referenced question. Right?

Comment: @yujaiyu It is, because `self.x` is an &Option, which is the issue in the question. My explaination is why you have ended up with &Option.

Comment: @cafce25 Does it? Have you tried it in the playground?

Comment: Maye slightly more context, but trying to change a duplicate target is a pain.

Comment: @user1937198 No. `self.x` is an `Option` and `&self.x` doesn't get you to the point when you can apply the answer from the referenced question. Please try it in the playground that I've linked.

Comment: `as_ref` works when you don't try to make a value out of a reference, so does matching.

Comment: @user1937198 Yeah... I know changing a duplicate target is hard... The problem is that people stopped reading questions here many many years ago. :(

Comment: @cafce25 Therefore it does not work for the given example.

Comment: Well nothing works for the given example, that's not how [ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html) works in Rust.

Comment: @cafce25 Can we then agree on the obvious: the question is not a duplicate? Let's allow people to answer the question.

Comment: The part you're complaining about is fundamentally not possible (see the books chapter), the other part of the question is explained in the dupe. I don't see anything to add here.

Comment: @cafce25 What is not possible? What exact line is "making value out of reference"? I am also genuinely asking a question, I am not complaining. The language in my question cannot be more neutral than it already is.

Comment: @cafce25 Note that `fn my_fn(arg1: &Option<Box<i32>>) -> i32` from the referenced question does exactly that: receives a reference and returns a value.

Comment: @yujaiyu `A::foo` takes a reference but `print_enum` takes a value. That's the disconnect. Somewhere between those two you _have_ to clone the value, which is how you "make a value out of a reference." The solution, as mentioned before, is to have `print_enum` take a reference and not a value.

Comment: @yujaiyu That's because `i32` implements `Copy` and so is trivially-copyable. Your type `BOrC` implements neither `Copy` (because it cannot since `String` also cannot) nor `Clone` (because you have not implemented it explicitly or by deriving). If you derive `Clone` you can make this work though with some waste, as a clone here isn't necessary if you just change `print_enum` to take a reference as you've already been advised to.

Comment: @yujaiyu So if you add `#[derive(Clone)]` to `BOrC` then you can do `self.x.as_ref().unwrap().clone()` to get a copy, which can be passed to `print_enum`. But there is no reason that `print_enum` needs ownership of the value in the first place.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks! That "disconnect" point is what I missed in 
user1937198's answer.